# MySQL 5.7 + PHP fetch_assoc returns Blank

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning React + php backend + MySQL and got stuck in this problem:

The web host I am using uses MySQL version 5.7.
My PC usees MySQL 8.2.

Code I am having the problem:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `usuario` WHERE `login` = ?;";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$login]);

$result = $stmt->get_result();

$results = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

When i run the backend mysqli->fetch_assoc() on localhost, it gets all the right values in my query.
but, when i run the same code on WebHost, it returns nothing.

I already did some testing, and the problem is on the fetch_assoc + MySQL 5.7.
fetch_all() works fine in this case

I tried using fetch_all and fetch_assoc beetween MySQL 5.7 and 8.2

Edit:

Enabled error reporting. Nothing new.
PHP version in both systems is 8.2.13

Edit2: If anyone wanna try replicating the error:

```
_install latest Wamp Server with MySQL 5.7 add-on.
_Clone Github repo: https://github.com/leyed0/testes
_Create a vitual host named 'testes' pointing to the folder 'backend' in the repository.
npm i
npm run start
```

with the react app running, show the browser console and click the button

edit 3:
I am being specific. It returns nothing at all. No error, no null, no characters... the console output when i log in a working system:

Echo code:

```
case 'GET':
        echo json_encode(['testado', 'GET', $_SERVER, $results, $gene]);
        break;

    case 'POST':
        echo json_encode(['testado', 'POST', $_SERVER, $results, $gene]);
        break;
```

output with SQL 8:

```
post or get
line with data
rest of the code
```

output with SQL 5:

```
post or get
rest of the code
```

theres no error being thrown ever

Edit 4:
So, i did vardump and it show code that makes sense.

var_dump($stmt):

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>C:\Leyed\REPO\testes\backend\index.php:76:</small>
<b>object</b>(<i>mysqli_stmt</i>)[<i>2</i>]
  <i>public</i> 'affected_rows' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>1</font>
  <i>public</i> 'insert_id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>0</font>
  <i>public</i> 'num_rows' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>0</font>
  <i>public</i> 'param_count' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>1</font>
  <i>public</i> 'field_count' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>14</font>
  <i>public</i> 'errno' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>0</font>
  <i>public</i> 'error' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>''</font> <i>(length=0)</i>
  <i>public</i> 'error_list' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
      <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
  <i>public</i> 'sqlstate' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'00000'</font> <i>(length=5)</i>
  <i>public</i> 'id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>1</font>
</pre>
```

var_dump($result):

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>C:\Leyed\REPO\testes\backend\index.php:76:</small>
<b>object</b>(<i>mysqli_result</i>)[<i>3</i>]
  <i>public</i> 'current_field' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>0</font>
  <i>public</i> 'field_count' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>14</font>
  <i>public</i> 'lengths' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
  <i>public</i> 'num_rows' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>1</font>
  <i>public</i> 'type' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>0</font>
</pre>
```

var_dump($results):

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>C:\Leyed\REPO\testes\backend\index.php:76:</small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=14)</i>
  'ID' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>2</font>
  'Login' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'leyed'</font> <i>(length=5)</i>
  'Senha' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'$2y$10$fm8FKZ2NfEO3YEkTmW8M6uHMIVCbhwvG8ICtg/hxJ1gSSCVWY5BAq'</font> <i>(length=60)</i>
  'Nome' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>''</font> <i>(length=0)</i>
  'CPF' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>''</font> <i>(length=0)</i>
  'Genero' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>''</font> <i>(length=0)</i>
  'Email' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'leyed94@gmail.com'</font> <i>(length=17)</i>
  'Telefone' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>''</font> <i>(length=0)</i>
  'Nascimento' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'1994-08-12'</font> <i>(length=10)</i>
  'Endere�o' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>0</font>
  'Criado' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'2023-12-18 22:24:10'</font> <i>(length=19)</i>
  'UltLogin' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'2023-12-21 23:46:32'</font> <i>(length=19)</i>
  'Desde' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'2023-12-18 22:24:10'</font> <i>(length=19)</i>
  'Permisses' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>''</font> <i>(length=0)</i>
</pre>
```

I am going to replicate this in the SQL 8 version (that works) to see if I spot any differences

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: PHP versions on both systems are the same? Have you tried inverting the connections to rule out the issue being PHP?

Comment: Enabled error reporting. Nothing new. PHP version in both systems is 8.2.13

Comment: Not sure about passing the bind params in the call to `execute`, for mysqli you would normally pass them using `bind_param`.

Comment: You'll need to be little bit more specific because "nothing" is not really a PHP concept. According to [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), you can also get "`null` if there are no more rows in the result set, or `false` on failure" (yes, mysqli is extremely counter-intuitive). You can inspect variables with a step debugger or poor-man's [var_dump()](https://php.net/var_dump).

Comment: I am being specific...

Comment: You're not doing enough debugging if you have nothing. `var_dump($stmt, $result, $results)` gives what?

Comment: You enabled PHP errors, mysqli errors, or both? Please add code where you are enabling error reporting

Comment: Sorry guys. As i said, I am still learning.
I am going to post a edit with vardump

Comment: In the future if posting here you should copy the plain text of the var_dump. It looks like this include HTML formatting that xdebug added... but sounds like you solved your issue so nice work.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem!
Thanks to @user3783243 - var_dump helped me.

The problem is with special characters (ç, ã, etc) being used in the SQL colum names.
I am brazillian and here those are so commom that sometimes we forget they are not standard.
MySQL 8 handle those characters easy, but MySQL 5 have some problems with them and returns garbage - that makes php get confused.
I replaced special characters with simple ones and now the code works.

Maybe setting a different charset or collation should work too. But I decided to go the easy way and just change the colums needed

Comment: Tablenames and fields should consist of only ASCII characters, should not contain spaces, commas, semicolon, mathematical symbols and other "weird" stuff.